# how can I fix conflicting query string params for S3 uploads?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, react-native

I'm attempting to upload raw image data to S3 in the context of a react-native app.

I have the raw data correct and for the most part I think my code inside react native is working correctly to capture image data.

On my rails server, I'm using the amazon ruby gem to build the details of the url and associated authentication data required to post data to the bucket in question which I'm then rendering into react-native just like a regular react web front end.

```
# inside the rails server controller
s3_data = S3_BUCKET.presigned_post(key: "uploads/#{SecureRandom.uuid}/${filename}", success_action_status: '201', acl: 'public-read', url: 'https://jd-foo.s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com')
render json: {s3Data: {fields: s3_data.fields, url: s3_data.url}}
```

At the moment I attempt to post to S3, I'm using ES6 fetch like the below to build my http request.

```
    saveImage(data) {
    var url = data.url
    var fields = data.fields
    var headers = {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'}
    var body = `x-amz-algorithm=${encodeURIComponent(fields['x-amz-algorithm'])}&` + 
        `x-amz-credential=${encodeURIComponent(fields['x-amz-credential'])}&` + 
        `x-amz-date=${encodeURIComponent(fields['x-amz-date'])}&` +
        `x-amz-signature=${encodeURIComponent(fields['x-amz-signature'])}&` +
        `acl=${encodeURIComponent(fields['acl'])}&` +
        `key=${encodeURIComponent(fields['key'])}&` +
        `policy=${encodeURIComponent(fields['policy'])}&` +
        `success_action_status=${encodeURIComponent(fields['success_action_status'])}&` +
        `file=${encodeURIComponent('12foo')}`
    console.log(body);
    return fetch(url, {method: 'POST', body: body, headers: headers})
        .then((res) =>  {console.log('s3 inside api res', res['_bodyText']) ; res.json()} );
}
```

the logging of the body looks like

```
x-amz-algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&x-amz-credential=AKIAJJ22D4PSUNBB5RAQ%2F20151027%2Fus-west-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&x-amz-date=20151027T223159Z&x-amz-signature=42b09d7ae134f803b10ef72d220fe74a630a3f826c7f1f625448277d0a6d93c7&acl=public-read&key=uploads%2F46be8ca3-6d3a-4bb7-a658-f2c8e058bc28%2F%24%7Bfilename%7D&policy=eyJleHBpcmF0aW9uIjoiMjAxNS0xMC0yN1QyMzozMTo1OVoiLCJjb25kaXRpb25zIjpbeyJidWNrZXQiOiJqZC1mb28ifSxbInN0YXJ0cy13aXRoIiwiJGtleSIsInVwbG9hZHMvNDZiZThjYTMtNmQzYS00YmI3LWE2NTgtZjJjOGUwNThiYzI4LyJdLHsic3VjY2Vzc19hY3Rpb25fc3RhdHVzIjoiMjAxIn0seyJhY2wiOiJwdWJsaWMtcmVhZCJ9LHsieC1hbXotY3JlZGVudGlhbCI6IkFLSUFKSjIyRDRQU1VOQkI1UkFRLzIwMTUxMDI3L3VzLXdlc3QtMS9zMy9hd3M0X3JlcXVlc3QifSx7IngtYW16LWFsZ29yaXRobSI6IkFXUzQtSE1BQy1TSEEyNTYifSx7IngtYW16LWRhdGUiOiIyMDE1MTAyN1QyMjMxNTlaIn1dfQ%3D%3D&success_action_status=201&file=12foo
```

It seems like my problems could be tied to both

1. Bad format of the post body including problems with special characters
2. Not providing S3 with enough data in post body including keys and other information, the documentation feels a bit unclear about what is/is not required.

The error back from S3 servers looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>MalformedPOSTRequest</Code><Message>The body of your POST request is not well-formed multipart/form-data.</Message>    <RequestId>DCE88AC349D7B2E8</RequestId><HostId>AKE1xctETuZMAhBFLfyuFlDxikYUlbAC7YufkM7h8Z8eVQdtLA25Z0Od/a4cMUbfW1nWnGjc+vM=</HostId></Error>
```

I'm pretty unclear on what my actual problems are and where I should be digging in.

Any input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Did you ever manage to successfully upload an image to s3 using a presigned URL? I've wasted like 5 days on this problem

Comment: @user2689931 i realized that building that multipart post was not something that was going to be possible given the time and tooling inside react native so I passed the base64 image data to a rails server and then post the data to S3 from the server, not the device, which in retrospect seems a better pattern.

Answer (score 0):

```
<Message>The body of your POST request is not well-formed multipart/form-data.</Message>
```

It may not be that you're missing values from the body.  The most significant issue here is that the structure of your body does not resemble `multipart/form-data`.

See [RFC 2388](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2388.txt) for how `multipart/form-data` works.  (Or find a library that builds this for you.)

What you are sending looks more like the  [`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application/x-www-form-urlencoded) format, which is used by some AWS APIs, but not S3.

[There is an example in the S3 docs](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-post-example.html) showing what an example `POST` body might look like.  You should see a substantial difference there.

---

Note also that `POST` is intended for browser based uploads.  If you are uoloading from code, you're doing a lot of extra work.  [`PUT` Object](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTObjectPUT.html) is much more straightforward.  The request body is the binary file contents.  Or, if this will eventually be done by a browser, then test it with a browser, and let the browser build your form.